# Motion blur not quite like real camera motion blur - cycles

Tags: motion-blur

I have been attempting to render a warehouse scene with a package moving down a conveyor belt, with the idea that I would get a motion blur that match what a still camera would get with a dragged shutter. The rest of the scene looks pretty good to me but the motion blur looks really weird. It looks more like a flash has gone off rather than

I couldn't find a simple explaination (ie: one that my artist brain could wrap itself around!), so I am hoping someone here can give me a place to start.

Motion blur is checked. The shutter is set to 30.00. What am I missing to get the smoother blur across the box?

[image: Motion blur: real world vs blender scene]

Comment: To replicate the motion blur we're used to seeing in images from motion pictures or video cameras, set the shutter time to 0.5. Smaller numbers will result on more static images. Larger numbers will result in exaggerated motion blur.

Comment: Thanks @cegaton. I did figure it out after pulling a bunch of test renders. Of course, the amount of motion blur ends up being a longer shutter speed AND the speed of the objects in motion. I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer: I had set two key frames in the timeline, moving the boxes in between the two. And, then I had set the green line to the last key frame.

This meant that the boxes stopped on that frame. I needed to set the green line to a spot in between the two lines to show the blur on the motion of the boxes.

Simple!

[image: the right motion blur]